# Does multiplication by a test function stay in a Sobolev space?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, smooth-functions

> Let $u \in D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.
>   Then do we necessarily have $u\phi \in D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$?

#### My attempt

What we need to show is that $\partial_i (u \phi) \in L^{p_i}(\Omega)$ for each $i$. We can try to break up the integral as:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_i (u \phi)|^{p_i}
&=
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_i u \cdot \phi + \partial_i \phi \cdot u|^{p_i}
\leq
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_i u \cdot \phi|^{p_i} + \int_{\Omega} |\partial_i \phi \cdot u|^{p_i}
\\
&=
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_i u|^{p_i} |\phi|^{p_i} + \int_{\Omega} |\partial_i \phi|^{p_i} |u|^{p_i}
\end{align*}

The first term is easily bounded given the nature of $\phi$ and $u$. But, the second term is more troublesome. We can bound the size of $|\partial_i \phi|$ and restrict the integral to a compact set. Then if $p_i \leq p^*$, we can easily bound our integral by $|\operatorname{supp} \partial_i \phi| + \|u\|_{p^*}$, which is finite since $D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ is embedded in $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$. But we don't necessarily always have $p_i \leq p^*$; in this case, I don't know what to do.

#### Background

For $\vec{p} = (p_1, ..., p_N)$ and $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$, the Sobolev space $D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ is defined as the completion of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with respect to the norm:
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{\vec{p}} = \sum \limits_{i=1}^N \|\partial_i u \|_{p_i}
\end{align*}
We think of this space as being continuously embedded into $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$ via the Sobolev inequality given [here](https://eudml.org/doc/19616), where $p^* = Np/(N-p)$ and $1/p = \sum 1/p_i$.

Comment: Huh?  $\phi\in C_c^\infty$, so $\lVert\partial_i\phi\rVert_\infty$ are bounded.

Comment: @user10354138 Sure, so we bound $|\partial_i \phi|^{p_i}$ by a constant $C$, and we get $C \int_{\operatorname{supp} \partial_i \phi} |u|^{p_i}$. But how do we know this integral is finite?

Comment: Use $u\in D^{1,p}$.

Comment: @user10354138 How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for convenience, let $K:=[a,b]^n$ for $a<b$ s.t. supp $\phi\subseteq K$. By the steps you already made in the question, we are left to bound
   $$\| u\|_{p_i}^{p_i}=\int_K dy~ |u(y)|^{p_i}\,,$$
for any $i$. Let us first assume that $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subseteq C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. With the neat shorthand notation $((x,y)):=(y_1,\ldots,y_{i-1},x,y_i,\ldots,y_{n-1}))$, we have
\begin{align}
    \int_K dy~ |u(y)|^{p_i}&=\int_a^b dx\int_{[a,b]^{n-1}}dy|u((x,y))|^{p_i}\\
    &\leq(b-a)\sup_{x'\in[a,b]}\int_{[a,b]^{n-1}}dy~|u((x',y))|^{p_i}\\
    &\leq(b-a)\sup_{x'\in[a,b]}\int_a^{x'} dx\int_{[a,b]^{n-1}}dy~ p_i|u((x,y))|^{p_i-1}|\partial_i u((x,y))|\\
    &\leq (b-a)p_i\int_K dy~|u(y)|^{p_i-1}|\partial_i u(y)|\,,
\end{align}
where, in the second to last step, we have used the fundamental theorem of calculus, together with the fact that $\partial_i|f|\leq|\partial_if|$ where $f$ stays away from zero.
Let us denote $\| f\|_{p,K}=(\int_K |f|^p)^{1/p}$. When we use Hölder's inequality on the above, we find
   $$\| u\|_{p_i,K}^{p_i}\leq \left\||u|^{p_i-1}\right\|_{q,K}\Vert\partial_iu\|_{p_i,K}$$
for $q$ with $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p_i}=1$. Since this implies $q(p_i-1)=p_i$ as well as $p_i/q=p_i-1$, the definitions give us
   $$\| |u|^{p_i-1}\|_{q,K}=\|u\|_{p_i,K}^{p_i-1}\,.$$
The following trick is a true classic! Note that we have obtained
   $$\|u\|^{p_i}_{p_i,K}\leq (b-a)p_i\|u\|_{p_i,K}^{p_i-1}\|\partial_iu\|_{p_i},$$
in which we can move $\| u\|_{p_i,K}^{p_i-1}$ to the left, and find
  $$\|u\|_{p_i,K}\leq (b-a)p_i\|\partial_iu\|_{p_i}\,.$$
Remember, we only proved this inequality for $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Still, it implies that a Cauchy sequence $(u_n)$ in $D^{1,\vec{p}}$ is a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{p_i,K}$ as well, implying that $\|\lim u_n\|_{p_i,K}<\infty$. Thus we have $\|u\|_{p_i,K}<\infty$ for any $u\in D^{1,\vec{p}}$, which means the answer to your question is... yes.

Comment: Fantastic! Did you come up with this yourself, or is it from a reference? It seems that you show something stronger, namely that $u \in L^{p_i}_{loc}(\Omega)$. This seems like an important result!

Comment: I'm also curious about the "pass to the completion" step. My idea is to a sequence $u_n$ converging to $u$ in $D^{1,\vec{p}}$ and also pointwise a.e. (extracting a subsequence). Fatou's lemma tells us that the norm of $u$ is less or equal to the limit of the $u_n$ norms, and we apply your inequality to get less or equal to the limit of the $\partial_i u_n$ norms. This is equal to the norm of $\partial_i u$ since $D^{1,\vec{p}}$ convergence implies convergence of the partials in $L^{p_i}$.

Comment: Yes, that's the right approach if you see $D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ as a subset of $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$. If you see $D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ as the abstract completion of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (and assume wlog that $\Omega\subseteq K$) then you can canonically embed it in $L^{p_i}(K)$, and you will automatically get this bound.

Comment: I came up with this myself. It was a nice problem for the weekend. :) Now that I've looked in the literature I read that, at least for some different variant of $D^{1,p}$ this is apparently referred to as `common knowledge': https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9abc/ebe4bb8d6f8e348ef019253f25ae7462c19b.pdf.

Comment: Indeed, I was considering $D^{1,\vec{p}}(\Omega)$ as embedded into $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$. By the "canonical embedding" into $L^{p_i}(K)$, do you mean identifying the Cauchy sequence $(u_n)_n$ with the limit of $(\partial_i u_n)_n$? If so, I don't see how to even make sense of the inequality in that case.

Comment: You have a good point. By canonical embedding I meant $\iota:D^{1,\vec{p}}\hookrightarrow L^{p_i}(K)$, defined by $\iota(u):=u$ on the dense subset $C_c^{\infty}$ and extended by (Cauchy) continuity to $D^{1,\vec{p}}$. However, to get the inequality one first needs to define what $\partial_i u$ means for $u\in D^{1,\vec{p}}$. I now see that this is unnecesarily complicated, as you only need $\|u\|_{p_i,K}<\infty$. I will edit my answer.